# Do I need a wildcard ssl certificate for subdomains in Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

In our Azure subscription, we have 3 apps: dev.myapp.com, test.myapp.com, prod.myapp.com (www.myapp.com, myapp.com).

Previously I just purchased a wildcard cert, and then converted it to PFX format and uploaded it.

But I see now that I can get an SSL cert directly from Azure, and save a bit of hassle. But I am wondering if I buy an S1 certificate, if I can use it with my subdomains, or if I need to buy the wildcard (which is quite expensive compared to getting it from another source).

I assume I need the wildcard, would just like to confirm.

Comment: I ended up buying the wildcard at the inflated price. For those interested, the cert is actually issued by GoDaddy. You are just paying  about a 500% markup for the convenience of not having to bother creating a PFX file yourself, or with some conversion tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sheamus,

I can confirm you'll have to buy a `W1` Wild Card certificate: `*.myapp.com`.

A `S1` Standard certificate will only cover your domain `myapp.com` (Upon submission the certificate will also be approved for www.myapp.com).

Also you can refer to the following Azure documentation:

[Purchase, Store and Assign an SSL Certificate for your custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#a-purchase-store-and-assign-an-ssl-certificate-for-your-custom-domain-a)

> If you need to secure multiple domain names, such as contoso.com,
>   www.contoso.com, and mail.contoso.com, then you can get a wildcard
>   certificate

Answer (score 0):

You can either get the Single domain certificates or else you can go with the Wildcard SSL Certificates.

The Individual **Single Domain SSL certificate** will cost you low if you are going to buy from Comodo, but as it is for one domain you have to create the new CSR and Private Key for each domain. If you are wishing to secure one more app, you need to purchase a new SSL, New CSR & Private Key... This is really

But in the case of **Wildcard SSL**, the one CSR and Private Key will work for all your sub-domains. additionally, it will allow you to secure any number of sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can take either single domain SSL or Wildcard SSL certificate to secure sub domains.

If the time of the various SSL certificate management does not matter to you, but the price is important then go for a single domain SSL certiifcate, otherwise go for [Wildcard SSL certificate which secures number of sub domains](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/what-is-wildcard-ssl-certificate).

If have price concern for wildcard ssl certificate then go with comodo certificate authority resellers.